# CSP: How I can allow to download a specific content type

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, xss

currently, I try to download a specific document  with a csp rule that is activated as such:

> default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
>   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self';
>   frame-src 'self';img-src 'self' data:; object-src 'self';

How I can allow a specific file with this content-type (it's a pdf file):

> text/html;charset=utf-8

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Content-Type", "application/pdf" if you are looking for a PDF type. If you are using JavaScript add below line,

```js
this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
```